# Merge to different dictionaries

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary

I have two lists of dictionaries like this:

```
dic1 = [{'Age': 8, 'Pets Name': 'Felix', 'Species': 'Cat'}, {'Age': 57, 'Pets Name': 'Michelangelo', 'Species': 'Tortoise'}, {'Age': 12, 'Pets Name': 'Rantanplan', 'Species': 'Dog'}, {'Age': '2', 'Pets Name': 'Nemo', 'Species': 'Fish'}, {'Age': '45', 'Pets Name': 'Leonardo', 'Species': 'Tortoise'}, {'Age': 9, 'Pets Name': 'Milo', 'Species': 'Dog'}, {'Age': 57, 'Pets Name': 'Raphael', 'Species': 'Tortoise'}, {'Age': '4', 'Pets Name': 'Dory', 'Species': 'Fish'}]
dic2 = [{'Pets Names': 'Michelangelo', "Owner's Names": 'Ana'}, {'Pets Names': 'Dory', "Owner's Names": 'Eva'}, {'Pets Names': 'Rantanplan', "Owner's Names": 'Ada'}, {'Pets Names': 'Leonardo', "Owner's Names": 'Ana'}, {'Pets Names': 'Felix', "Owner's Names": 'Eva'}, {'Pets Names': 'Raphael', "Owner's Names": 'Ana'}, {'Pets Names': 'Nemo', "Owner's Names": 'Eva'}]
```

I need to make a third list of dictionaries, being the keys (of the dictionaries) the owner's names, and the values the age of their respective pets. For example, given the two lists above, the output should be:

```
dic3 = [{'Ana': [57, 45, 57]}, {'Eva': [4, 8, 2]}, {'Ada': [12]}]
```

The main goal is to get the average of the each owner's pets ages but I think I can do it myself after I have the desired dict.
So far I only have this:

```
def merge_dicts(dic1,dic2):

   name = [li['Pets Name'] for li in dic1]
   age = [li['Age'] for li in dic1]
   owenrsName = [li["Owner's Names"] for li in dic2]
```

This gives me the lists of the name of the pets, their age, and the name of the owner's, but I don't know if it's relevant for the final function.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dic1 = [{'Age': 8, 'Pets Name': 'Felix', 'Species': 'Cat'}, {'Age': 57, 'Pets Name': 'Michelangelo', 'Species': 'Tortoise'}, {'Age': 12, 'Pets Name': 'Rantanplan', 'Species': 'Dog'}, {'Age': '2', 'Pets Name': 'Nemo', 'Species': 'Fish'}, {'Age': '45', 'Pets Name': 'Leonardo', 'Species': 'Tortoise'}, {'Age': 9, 'Pets Name': 'Milo', 'Species': 'Dog'}, {'Age': 57, 'Pets Name': 'Raphael', 'Species': 'Tortoise'}, {'Age': '4', 'Pets Name': 'Dory', 'Species': 'Fish'}]
dic2 = [{'Pets Names': 'Michelangelo', "Owner's Names": 'Ana'}, {'Pets Names': 'Dory', "Owner's Names": 'Eva'}, {'Pets Names': 'Rantanplan', "Owner's Names": 'Ada'}, {'Pets Names': 'Leonardo', "Owner's Names": 'Ana'}, {'Pets Names': 'Felix', "Owner's Names": 'Eva'}, {'Pets Names': 'Raphael', "Owner's Names": 'Ana'}, {'Pets Names': 'Nemo', "Owner's Names": 'Eva'}]



def merge_dicts(dic1,dic2):
    dict3= {}
    result = []
    name = [li['Pets Name'] for li in dic1]
    age = [li['Age'] for li in dic1]
    owenrsName = [li["Owner's Names"] for li in dic2]


    for d2 in dic2:

       pname = d2['Pets Names']
       oname = d2["Owner's Names"]

       if oname not in dict3:
            dict3[oname] = []

       for d1 in dic1:
           if d1['Pets Name'] == pname:
               dict3[oname].append(d1['Age'])
    for key,value in dict3.items():
        result.append({key:value})

    print(result)


merge_dicts(dic1,dic2)
```

o/p

```
[{'Ada': [12]}, {'Eva': ['4', 8, '2']}, {'Ana': [57, '45', 57]}]
```

Comment: 1. What was the point of putting it into a function if the actual functionality is hard-coded and not generalizable? 2. It doesn't even produce the new dictionary. It prints it out and then throws it away. 3. Not a big issue, but you could use `setdefault()` or a `defaultdict`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use simply comprehensions:

```
{ name : [ d['Age'] for d in dic1 if d['Pets Name']
          in [ d2['Pets Names'] for d2 in dic2 if d2["Owner's Names"] == name ] ]
      for name in set(( d["Owner's Names"] for d in dic2)) }
```

Answer (score 2):

Using some shortcuts :

```
def merge_dicts(dic1,dic2):
    ages = { li['Pets Name']:li['Age'] for li in dic1 }
    owners = { li["Owner's Names"]:li['Pets Name'] for li in dic2 }
    result = {}
    for owner, pet in owners.items():
        if owner in result :
            result[owner].append(ages[pet])
        else:
            result[owner] = [ages[pet]]
```

Then your result is a dictionnary of type `{'Eva': [4, 8, 2]}` but you can use a list comprehension to get it back to a list of dict if needed

```
    result = [ {k:v} for k,v in result ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a shorter version of Backtracks reply (which works fine, but I prefer shorter and functional when ever possible).

```
owners = {name: [] for name in list(set(map(lambda r: r["Owner's Names"], dic2)))}

for pet in dic1:
    for owner_mapping in dic2:
        if owner_mapping["Pets Names"] == pet["Pets Name"]:
            owners[ owner_mapping["Owner's Names"] ].append(pet["Age"])
```

EDIT to demonstrate iterating over the result set (`owners`):

```
for owners_name, pets_ages_list in owners.items():
    print owners_name
    print pets_ages_list
    for pet_age in pets_ages_list:
        print pet_age
```

Comment: Thank you! How can I iterate through the result list to get only the values list of eachs dict?

Comment: Easy: `for owners_name, pets_ages_list in owners.items(): ...` :) That will leave you with `pets_ages_list` being `[12]` then `[4,8,2]` and finally `[57,45,57]`.

Comment: That only gives me the list of the ages of the first owner, how can I get all of them? Sorry about the nagging :)

Comment: @Stagg no worries what so ever, I've edited my reply to show how to iterate over the resulting dict.